# Unit of maxDistance in Near<T> (MongoDB C# Driver)

Tags: c#, mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

What is the unit type for `maxDistance` argument of the `Query<U>.Near<T>` method (in MongoDB C# Driver)?

Notes: I have created an index and I have checked that it's a "2d" index:

```
var keys = IndexKeys<Loc>.GeoSpatial<double[]>(l => l.Coordinates);
var options = IndexOptions.SetName("Loc_Coordinates").SetBackground(true);
Locations.EnsureIndex(keys, options);
```

And index checked by:

```
var idxes = Locations.GetIndexes();
foreach (var i in idxes)
{
    Program.Log(i.Key);
}
```

Indexes are:

```
{ "_id" : 1 }
{ "Coordinates" : "2d" }
```

I thought the unit should be radian, so I wrote this helper method to convert meter to radian:

```
const double EarthRadius_m = 6371.01 * 1000d; //m
public static double MeterToRadian(this double meter) { return meter / EarthRadius_m; }
```

But if I use meter (in a dense area), I get too much results and if I use radian, I get nothing **unless** it's big (multiplied by 1000!). Maybe `MeterToRadian` has some problems? Or the unit is `km` instead of `m`? (But on the website, it says it's meter).

I query the collection by this code:

```
var radius = meter.MeterToRadian();
var query = Query<Loc>.Near<double[]>(l => l.Coordinates, lon, lat, radius);
var answer = Locations.Find(query).SetLimit(limit).ToList();
```

Comment: @haim770 Thanks for the in time edit; very kind of you!

Comment: could you include the line which does the actual query (in radians since that *is* the expected unit)?

Comment: also you say you verify the index is "2d" but I don't see any output - could you connect to mongodb via mongo shell and type "use <db>" (fill in name of your database) and then "db.locations.getIndexes()" and post the output here?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Yes; I get some output when I choose a bigger radius (and BTW the performance is awful!).

Comment: can you include the output of index verification?  I'm wondering if you really have a "2d" index on the appropriate fields.  One way you can check is after the query runs slowly it will be recorded in the mongod logs - it may be possible to tell from that if it's using an index.  Meanwhile output of collection.getIndexes() would be very helpful.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I've added the output.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I guess if I was on a machine with more RAM then performance will get improved drastically; because my whole data and index would fit into it's RAM. I would try at first opportunity I got on a big server.

Comment: all your data does not need to fit into RAM - but indexes should. If you want to debug performance, I would suggest using explain() on this query.  It might be easier to debug from the mongo shell - that would also rule out any driver related (or usage) problems...  How much RAM do you have on this machine?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky 4 GB; But on server I have ~90 GB. My db size on disk is 4.3 GB and I have ~2,100,000 documents in my collection. And my benchmark was faulty. Even on this machine MongoDB can perform more than 1900 `Near` searches! Thanks! BTW by any chance, had you encounter a reference that says what unit I should use?

Comment: you should use radians. what you are doing appears to be correct, that's why I'd like to get to the bottom of what's going on - going to mongo shell and running this query with .explain() appended will show the query plan for it and that would be able to answer a lot of questions about why it doesn't seem to be working correctly.  I think mongodb-users google group may be a better place to take this discussion as this isn't a straight Q&A at this point.